# Need help removing JLabel from ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jlabel

I have a program that has an ArrayList of JLabels called handNumberList.  The method getHand() is used to display the list of JLabels in the beginning of the program when I am creating a panel.

```
public JPanel getHand()
{        
    if (firstUpdate == 0)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++)
        {
            hand.add(index + 1);
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < hand.size(); index++)
        { 
            handNumberList.add(getLabel(Integer.toString(hand.get(index))));
            handNumberList.get(index).setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));

            addComp(handPanel, handNumberList.get(index), 2 * index, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.2,
                  GridBagConstraints.BOTH, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);

        }
    }

    firstUpdate = 1;


    return handPanel;
}
```

After that I press a button and the button is supposed to remove two components in both the ArrayList hand (made of Integers) and the handNumberList.  When the code is ran it removes the components from hand just fine but nothing happens to handNumberList and everything stays the same on the panel.

```
for (int index = 0; index < hand.size(); index++)
{
    if (firstNumber == hand.get(index))
    {
        handNumberList.remove(index);
        hand.remove(index);
    }
}

for (int index = 0; index < hand.size(); index++)
{
    if (secondNumber == hand.get(index))
    {
        handNumberList.remove(index);
        hand.remove(index);
    }
}
```

It appears that everything works just fine aside from that.  Any help?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give any sense.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete as it contains references to several variables without the definitions of those variables.

Comment: Always ask your question with a view to our perspective, asking yourself -- "what would they need to fully understand my code and my problem?"

Comment: You shouldn't remove items from an ArrayList as you're doing, as the index changes as you remove items. Instead use an iterator and remove the items with the iterator.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - instead of storing `JLabel` components, it would probably be best to store the `String` content. Then when you've made that change, I recommend displaying those strings in a `JList` (using a `JLabel` as the renderer, which is the default)..

Answer (score 0):

> everything stays the same on the panel.

When removing (or adding) components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```